# How to determine the version of Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

How can I know which version of Gradle I am using in my Android Studio? Please guide.

I want to make sure I am using Gradle version 2.2.1.

Comment: In `build.gradle` you will find the version

Comment: @Roon13 No. in `build.gradle` you can find the plugin from android. The version of gradle is in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: Check here about different concepts of gradle version. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51392464/8034839 I.e. gradle version. Android Gradle plugin version and Android gradle wrapper.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

**Option 1- From Studio**

In Android Studio, go to File > Project Structure. Then select the "project" tab on the left.

Your Gradle version will be displayed here.

**Option 2- gradle-wrapper.properties**

If you are using the Gradle wrapper, then your project will have a `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` folder.

This file should contain a line like this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

This determines which version of Gradle you are using. In this case, `gradle-2.2.1-all.zip` means I am using Gradle 2.2.1.

**Option 3- Local Gradle distribution**

If you are using a version of Gradle installed on your system instead of the wrapper, you can run `gradle --version` to check.

Comment: Regarding **Option 3** this would work also when using the wrapper.

Comment: Yep, the only difference is that you should run `./gradlew --version` from your project's directory (or wherever your Gradle wrapper lives).

Comment: Option 1 doesn't make sense, since the value is mutable.

Comment: @nmz787 if you are changing that value, then the question of "what version am I using" is awfully silly, isn't it? The value is whatever you are setting. If you aren't changing it, then that is precisely the version that your builds are currently using.

Comment: I guess I was looking for "how to get all valid versions of gradle to use". Since I can enter 1234 for the version, but that doesn't actually mean it IS a version of gradle.

Comment: This is not technically correct. This file just indicates the version of gradle you have configured the project to use, and also should not be confused with the Android Gradle Plugin.
For instance, you coul dhave multiple versions of Gradle installed on your system, and this file would only indicate the Gradle Version your project is ATTEMPTING to use.
To actually determine which version of Gradle is installed on your system, which is what I believe OP is aksing, simply 
*open a terminal and type <gradle -v>* 
This will indicate which Gralde Version your system is currently using.

Comment: continued....  If you have the need to frequently switch between versions, I highly recommend sdkman as it is very easy ot set system defaults and also download specific versions.

Comment: This question is specifically about Gradle, not the Android Gradle Plugin.

The vast majority of Gradle users are also not using a version installed on their computer, and **should not be** because that leads to non-reproducible builds. However, I did include that version check as option three in case that is your configuration.

Comment: Option 2 works for checking the gradle version used by the project

Answer (score 60):

## Gradle Wrapper

I running the following in my project using the [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

```
./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-04-18 09:09:12 UTC
Revision:     b9a962bf70638332300e7f810689cb2febbd4a6c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_212 (AdoptOpenJDK 25.212-b03)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15 x86_64
```

Comment: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Comment: @Patriotic this command working on mac os and linux.

Answer (score 40):

## Build Script

You can also add the following line to your build script:

```
println "Running gradle version: $gradle.gradleVersion"
```

or (it won't be printed with `-q` switch)

```
logger.lifecycle "Running gradle version: $gradle.gradleVersion"
```

Comment: I tried this and got: "> Configure project :
Running gradle version: $gradle.gradleVersion"

Answer (score 18):

At the root of your project type below in the console:

```
gradlew --version
```

You will have gradle version with other information (as a sample):

```
------------------------------------------------------------          
Gradle 5.1.1 << Here is the version                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------          

Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC                                 
Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807                

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1                                                   
Kotlin:       1.3.11                                                  
Groovy:       2.5.4                                                   
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018  
JVM:          10.0.2 ("Oracle Corporation" 10.0.2+13)                 
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

I think for gradle version it uses `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` under the hood.

Comment: works flawlessly!

Comment: For anyone using react-native, gradlew.bat is located in {root project folder}\android

Comment: ./gradle --version on mac

Answer (score 8):

Go to Terminal & Type:

gradlew --version

---

### Gradle 5.3

Build time:   2019-03-20 11:03:29 UTC
Revision:     f5c64796748a98efdbf6f99f44b6afe08492c2a0

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64

Comment: In which directory? Mine says: "'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: For anyone using react-native, gradlew.bat is located in {root project folder}\android

Answer (score 2):

Another solution on windows is to locate the file "gradle.bat" (usually in Gradle\bin\ directory), then you launch it **from the command line** and you will get the version like so:

[image: terminal]

Answer (score 2):

## Checking in gradle-wrapper.properties

Check your `gradle-wrapper.properties` in Android project/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties.

You'll have something like this:
*distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/`gradle-6.5-bin`.zip*

## Using terminal

#### Windows:

run `gradlew --version`

#### Mac:

run `./gradlew --version`

in your project folder.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer for windows 10 in android studio, open the terminal inside android studio, then ensure you are in your app, if not navigate to where your app is then enter this command without the double quotes "./gradlew --version"

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution
Do change in your **cordovaLib file build.gradle** file

> dependencies {
>           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' }

and now make changes in you,

> platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
>
> distributionUrl=\
>   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

this works for.

Answer (score 1):

If importing the project try doing following steps:

1. Check Gradle version in command prompt `gradle --version`
2. While importing the project like below
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check in the folder structure of the project the files within the /gradle/wrapper/ 
The gradle-wrapper.jar version should be the one specified in the gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score -1):

2019-05-08
Android Studios needs an upgrade.
upgrade Android Studios to 3.3.- and the error with 
.R; goes away.

Also the above methods also work.

Answer (score -2):

replace this line in android\build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

Comment: That is a the Gradle plugin for Android, not The version of Gradle itself. To find which version to have installed ust open up a terminal and type 
gradle -v

Comment: @NicolasMage , why don't you add  this as an answer?