# Why am I getting "could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle" error?

Tags: gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, build-automation, build.gradle

This is based off my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958596/how-to-resolve-low-sdk-build-tools-error)  as well.

Following this [tutorial](https://github.com/MissionBit/mobile-game-dev/wiki/Push-Your-First-Android-Game), I cloned the project into my machine and am trying to get the project to build properly.

In the process of fixing the error I got in my last question, I encountered a new error. 
This is the section of the build script I am trying to fix/edit

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
         mavenCentral()
         mavenLocal()
         maven { url 'https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/raw/maven-repo/' }
      }
      dependencies {
            classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.3'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
      }
 }
```

Following the  [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054911/how-to-determine-the-version-of-gradle) on how to check Gradle version, I checked mine and saw that I was running Gradle version 2.2.1. Based off that, I changed

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

to

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
```

However after changing that build script code, and attempting to rebuild my project, I get the above mentioned error(full stack trace below)

```
    Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
    file:/C:/Users/chris/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    file:/C:/Users/chris/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
    https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/raw/maven-repo/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.pom
    https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/raw/maven-repo/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.1/gradle-2.2.1.jar
Required by:
    :theplanethatcouldntflygood:unspecified
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error or how to fix this? It doesn't make sense for me to point the Java compiler(classpath) at a Gradle Version that I am not even using.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are confusing between android gradle plugin and gradle version.

This `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'` is a gradle plugin for Android and as of this time, 1.2.3 is the latest.

The gradle version itself is in gradle-wrapper.properties file. 2.4 is the latest version,

Comment: ahh I see thank you!! Is the graddle-wrapper.properties file gradlew in Android Studio?

Comment: The fullpath is /gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. You could use the Navigate -> File and type in gradle-wrapper.properties. It should show up.

Answer (score 7):

Per @Hamidreza's answer, check the [maven](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle) and [jcenter](http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle) repos. Indeed jcenter (currently) has newer tools than maven.

So in the top-level `build.gradle` file,
change "mavenCentral" to "jcenter" like this

```
repositories {
    //mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: This seems incomplete. Did you post too early on accident? You can still [edit] your answer.

Answer (score 6):

you can find last version in this address :
[repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle)
 [jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle](http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this exact issue by upgrading my version of Android Studio. I was receiving an error `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0`, and was running a 2.1.x version of Studio at the time.

A simple upgrade to 2.2.2 immediately fixed my issue. Hope this can help somebody!

Answer (score 0):

If you're behind a proxy, make sure Android Studio is set up for that. It does NOT assume system proxy settings.

My copy of Studio + Gradle wasn't set up to go through the proxy, and as a result it was giving me this error. Would've been nice to get a clear "hey buddy, I can't hit the web", but I got this error instead.