# How to check version of gradle installed on my Mac?

Tags: gradle

I installed gradle using homebrew on Mac OS High Sierra. I wanted to check the version and if it's installed successfully on my laptop. I'm not using it for Android Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the version of Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054911/how-to-determine-the-version-of-gradle)

Answer (score 13):

To verify gradle version run:

`gradle -v` or `gradle --version`

More or less you should get:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.0-rc-3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-06-12 15:04:44 UTC
Revision:     78d6b5b1e5cdb3dd4e233eb2f2e2bf721c53ca9e

Groovy:       2.4.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.4 x86_64
```

Comment: Maybe ./gradle -v ?

Answer (score 10):

typing `./gradlew -v` in my project directory worked for me.

I `cd` ed into my project firectory.
And ran `./gradlew -v`